# Facebook Graph API Error: place search, latitude and longitude error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook's Graph API, I am trying to download the information for businesses within a fixed radius (in meters) from a given latitude and longitude. I am using an access token. I am importing the information into R using the function `callAPI(url,token)`

Here's the information I entered for the URL
`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000`

Documentation for this is here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/search/

I tried it for this particular latitude, longitude, and radius. These were the ones given in the example. I got 24 businesses. However, if I try to enter in any longitude and latitude other than that one, I get nothing.

Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work? I don't get why it works for one latitude and longitude but not another.

Comment: _“I don't get why it works for one latitude and longitude but not another.”_ - maybe because there are no such places around these coordinates within the given radius …?

Comment: No, I am trying places I know there are things with fb pages. I mean, it's possible some other aspect of my search is off. I don't know. For example, the link I posted made it sound like u are supposed to request the info you want in the "fields" section. I got a little bit better results with that, but not by much. Still got zero for many locations where I know places exist.